# Filtering a photo of a document to look like a proper scan

Tags: macos, photos, image-editing, adobe-photoshop, image-processing

So there are a couple of iOS apps that "scan" documents and automatically do some processing to make the image look like a quality scan from a real scanner.

When I'm trying this on the Mac with pictures from a DSLR manually with Photoshop the results are usually not as good as what these apps achieve.

Therefore I'm looking for either a Mac app or instructions for Photoshop on how to achieve this. Or maybe even an Automator script.

Just to be clear: I do not need OCR!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**ScanTailor**](http://scantailor.org).

> Scan Tailor is an interactive post-processing tool for scanned pages. It performs operations such as page splitting, deskewing, adding/removing borders, and others. You give it raw scans, and you get pages ready to be printed or assembled into a PDF or DJVU file.

The program is developed for Windows, GNU / Linux, and other Unix-like systems such as Mac OS X. See [Installation](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/wiki/User-Guide#installation-and-first-start) . You might need to build it from source though.

Comment: I do not know "wine" other then as a alcoholic drink.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Wine allows you to run Windows executables on Unix-like platforms (including OS X). http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX

Answer (score 0):

I found this Photoshop tutorial that might help. It's a semi-broken webpage without the images.
https://tricky-photoshop.com/make-document-looks-like-scanned-copy-photoshop
There's a video there that was useful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiwvTHLJ0gc&feature=emb_logo
Essentially, it looks like they crop, level to get rid of gray, then increase contrast before running it all through a high pass filter. I used it with a color photo (so I skipped black and white) and it looked pretty good.
I had the same question and am not a photoshop expert. But the instructions worked for me.